# How to Pass variable inside a curl command in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, curl

I am creating a bash script where I need to pass variable **$matchteams & $matchtime** into below curl command

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://5.12.4.7:3000/send' \
  --header 'Accept: */*' \
  --header 'User-Agent: Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
  "token": "abcdjbdifusfus",
  "title": "$matchteams | $matchtime",
  "msg": "hello all",
  "channel": "1021890237204529235"
}'
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: I see the problem is the old "I used `'` and as exactly the reason to do that, now `$` expressions aren't expanded"; but in general, it helps actually explaining what the problem is, i.e., saying what happens instead of what you expected.

Comment: `"{
  \"token\": \"abcdjbdifusfus\",
  \"title\": \"$matchteams | $matchtime\",
  \"msg\": \"hello all\",
  \"channel\": \"1021890237204529235\"
}"`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/772065/18306

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text inside single quotes is treated as literals:

```
--data-raw '{
  "token": "abcdjbdifusfus",
  "title": "$matchteams | $matchtime",
  "msg": "hello all",
  "channel": "1021890237204529235"
}'
```

(The double quotes surrounding your variables are also treated as literals.) In this case you need either to come out of the single quotes so that the variables will get parsed and expanded by the shell, or enclose the entire string in double quotes, escaping literal double quote marks appropriately:

```
# Swapping between single quote strings and double quote strings
--data-raw '{
  "token": "abcdjbdifusfus",
  "title": "'"$matchteams | $matchtime"'",
  "msg": "hello all",
  "channel": "1021890237204529235"
}'

# Enclosing the entire string in double quotes with escaping as necessary
--data-raw "{
  \"token\": \"abcdjbdifusfus\",
  \"title\": \"$matchteams | $matchtime\",
  \"msg\": \"hello all\",
  \"channel\": \"1021890237204529235\"
}"
```

Remember that `"abc"'def'` is expanded by the shell as `abcdef` so it's quite acceptable to swap quoting style mid-string. On balance I would tend to use the first style.